# Overstayed UK visa whilst waiting for my baby to be born

Tags: united-kingdom, overstay

I came into the UK 2 years ago on a 6 month visiting visa and luckily I met my girlfriend. We dated for a couple of months and she is now pregnant and due to give birth next year in March. Can I still make an application to the Home Office to be a permanent resident in the UK on the basis of my child and girlfriend and also to work and take care of them?

Comment: Your blatant and continuing overstay condition is likely to seriously harm your chances.

Comment: Although you are now illegally in the UK, you arrived on a visit visa; applying for another type of permission from within the UK is unlikely to result in a decision in your favor. Although the circumstances are slightly different, [read the the answer to the question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/106557/can-my-10-year-ban-be-lifted-now-that-i-have-a-baby-in-the-uk/106624#106624) before deciding how to go forward.

Comment: So you overstayed expecting to find a girlfriend, and expecting to have a baby, a year and a half down the line? Wow, nice crystal ball...